# Cohort Analysis - What kind of graph to use

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to plot a cohort analysis as in the Excel picture in this [link](http://www.alivelearn.net/?p=1240) or another example - [this picture](https://public.tableau.com/static/images/co/cohort-analysis/CohortAnalysis/1_rss.png) .

A short summary: a cohort analysis implies you have a matrix (n x n), with values under the main diagonal nulls (this is the data).

Example:

```
+----------+------+------+------+-----+  
|          | Jan  | Feb  | Mar  | Apr |  
+----------+------+------+------+-----+  
| January  | 100  | 90   | 80   |  30 |  
| February | null | 120  | 56   |  40 |  
| March    | null | null | 90   |  70 |  
| April    | null | null | null |  79 |  
+----------+------+------+------+-----+
```

The most appropriate chart I thought it would be is a *ComboChart* with `seriesType: 'area'` and `isStacked: true`, but it 's far away from showing as in the linked pictures above. JsFiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L3tNE/217/).

So I'm stuck, maybe another chart / options are required to achieve the rendering I need, maybe data needs to be structured in another way, maybe it 's not possible to do that with any google chart.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data needs to be setup in the opposite manner from excel,
switch the columns to rows, using an `AreaChart`.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Jan');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Feb');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Mar');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Apr');
  data.addColumn('number', 'May');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Jun');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Jul');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1),147,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 1),26,123,0,0,0,0,0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 1),24,29,149,0,0,0,0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 1),20,24,28,138,0,0,0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 1),20,20,22,22,130,0,0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 1),15,16,14,15,18,120,0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 1),14,14,12,14,20,29,110],
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    isStacked: true,
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I figure it out from a google spreadsheet that the series are the rows in fact, not the columns. https://ibb.co/db8WV7. Anyway this is the correct answer. Thank you!.